# MYSQL Query to replace a section of a string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, replace, substring

I have a ton of positions saved in a database in the following format

Examples:

```
[32.306,[7195.4,9414.24,0.005]]
[219.184,[7197.41,9416.66,-0.003]]
[161.215,[1170.26,4852.79,3.815e-04]]
[37.338,[479.163,3757.15,-0.005]]
[11.719,[12436.5,4780.36,-9.46e-04]]
```

The coordinates are in the format [DIRECTION,[X,Y,Z]]

I would like to replace all of the Z coordinates with 0. Been struggling with finding the correct way of doing this in an SQL query.

Comment: This is an example of bad table design. You should have different columns for each of these values.

Comment: It's not my application (its the game DayZ for those interested) unfortunately the database design is not something I have any control over but I agree with you for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8890/5)**

```
CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,',',3), ',0]]') col
```

Result:

```
|                           COL |
|-------------------------------|
|   [32.306,[7195.4,9414.24,0]] |
| [219.184,[7197.41,9416.66,0]] |
| [161.215,[1170.26,4852.79,0]] |
|  [37.338,[479.163,3757.15,0]] |
|  [11.719,[12436.5,4780.36,0]] |
```

Answer (score 1):

I would chop up the your string field using SUBSTRING and cast the values to floats and store them in 4 different fields (direction, x, y and z).
Then you can easily update the Z value (and any other value)

When you need the more complex string representation, just concatenate the 4 fields by casting it back to varchar.

Comment: Unfortunately the string needs to be stored in that format for the application concerned. Unless you just mean temporarily to do the update....